# photoshop cs3 scripting - apply gradient

Tags: photoshop-script, photoshop-cs3

i am trying to automate a task in photoshop cs3. i want to add a gradient to a layer. i could not find any methods or classes in the javascript reference regarding this.

i am able to set background color and foreground color and apply it to a selection like this

```
var docRef_1 = app.documents.add( 1000, 1000 )
docRef_1.artLayers.add(); 

var white = new SolidColor();
white.rgb["hexValue"] = "ffffff" 
var black = new SolidColor(); 
black.rgb["hexValue"] = "000000" 

foregroundColor = black; 
backgroundColor = white; 

docRef_1.selection.selectAll(); 
docRef_1.selection.fill(black); 
docRef_1.selection.deselect();
```

but i can not find any way to fill the selection with gradient.
i am wondering if this can be achieved only with executeAction as is the case with emboss and other specific filters which are not directly available in object model

but i guess, for that i need to have a scriptlistener and record the action and generate the javascript log.
can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, scripting gradients is not well documented (or implemented in my opinion). You'll need to use scriptlistener to glean the correct code. Keep in mind, the start and end positions of the gradient will be hard coded. If you want to vary the gradient's position by the selection's size, set it each point relative to `activeDocuments.selection.bounds`.

If you want to save a gradient for re-use, create a new layer and apply a gradient overlay. [See this answer on the graphic design SE site for more details](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/25467/16448).

Comment: thanks, i ll try this out. i dont want to have the extra burden of using the scriptlistener to record actions everytime, i think it would be really great if there was a repository of js log from scriptlistener for common tasks such as emboss and other filters and gradients, so that we could just change some input parameters and get desired result.